# How to use a user input variable across multiple unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, global-variables, googletest

I have a C++11 project with many googletest unit tests looking like

```
TEST_F(GTest, testSomething) {
    int64_t n = 42;
    // following code depends on input size n
    ...
}
```

Rather than having a local constant `n` in each test, I'd like to be able to set the input size from one location, preferably the command line:

```
./RunMyProgram --gtest_filter=* --n=1000
```

The `main` should look like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

     // TODO: parse command line argument n here

    INFO("=== starting unit tests ===");

    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();

}
```

With what should I replace `?` in my test functions?

```
TEST_F(GTest, testSomething) {
    int64_t n = ?;
    // following code depends on input size n
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you use the same value/parameter in more than one of your test functions, consider to use Fixtures.

What you are trying to do for me looks like a "value parameterized test". I guess thats rather common in testing world, and - tadaa, Google Test has a chapter in its advanced guide, called ["Value Parameterized Test"](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests) (and oh, it uses fixtures).

Comment: This would be the ideal solution. However, I have problems implementing this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14363874/626537

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *gtest* you could look into [gflags](http://code.google.com/p/gflags/) as well.  Then in `main.cpp` you could define the command line argument:

```
DEFINE_int64(n, 0, "some input arg");
```

and then in your test code you could declare it:

```
DECLARE_int64(n);
```

In your tests you would use it like this:

```
int64_t n = FLAGS_n;
```

Of course, if you wanted to parse the flags manually then you can define it in `main.cpp` yourself:

```
int64_t FLAGS_n;
```

And then declare it in your test files:

```
extern int64_t FLAGS_n;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this that way, you'll need to parse the command line args yourself (additionally to `InitGoogleTest`) and provide your values using e.g. global variables.

Comment: I understand that I need to parse the command line arguments myself. I omitted that because it is not my problem. Rather: Does googletest provide some support for doing what I'd like to do? Should I parse the arguments into global variables? How can I declare the global variables and how can I use them in the test code?

Comment: If you want to do it "manually" - where is the problem in defining a global variable and in using it for initialization of your local `n` variables? Its still good old C++.

Comment: Refer to the other answer from Arne Mertz. Using global variables will also work, refer to them in the testcode with `extern` declarations.

Comment: @ArneMertz I'm not used to programming with global variables, have never used them in C++ and would rather not do it manually.

Comment: @cls I did not want to suggest you should do it manually nor should you use global variables. However, doing so is very simple. (which is bad, because lots of newbie and seasoned programmers produce tons of ugly code using globals). For the nonmanual solution without globals see the link in my answer above :-)