# Googletest Parametrized tests crash

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I've just learned about [value-parametrized unit tests in googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests) and would like to use them in my project.

I wrote a simple parametrized test.

Header:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace EnsembleClustering {

class ParametrizedGTest: public testing::TestWithParam<int> {
public:
    ParametrizedGTest();
    virtual ~ParametrizedGTest();
};

} /* namespace EnsembleClustering */
```

Source:

```
#include "ParametrizedGTest.h"

namespace EnsembleClustering {

ParametrizedGTest::ParametrizedGTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

ParametrizedGTest::~ParametrizedGTest() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}


TEST_P(ParametrizedGTest, testParameter) {
    int n = GetParam();
    EXPECT_EQ(n, GetParam());
}


INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(ParametrizedGTestInstance,
                        ParametrizedGTest,
                        ::testing::Values(100));

} /* namespace EnsembleClustering */
```

Now, when I run googletest as usual, the program crashes without any output. The gdb stack trace is

```
EnsembleClustering-D [C/C++ Application]    
    EnsembleClustering  
        Thread [1] (Suspended : Signal : EXC_BAD_ACCESS:Could not access memory)    
            __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::_M_attach_single() at 0x100528add 
            __gnu_debug::_Safe_sequence_base::_M_attach() at 0x100528a74    
            __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator_base::_M_attach() at 0x100528bfe    
            __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator_base::_Safe_iterator_base() at safe_base.h:90 0x1000016e9   
            __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase**, std::__cxx1998::vector<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase*, std::allocator<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase*> > >, std::__debug::vector<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase*, std::allocator<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase*> > >::_Safe_iterator() at safe_iterator.h:154 0x100002e9c    
            std::__debug::vector<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase*, std::allocator<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase*> >::begin() at vector:207 0x100001fbe  
            testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseRegistry::GetTestCasePatternHolder<EnsembleClustering::ParametrizedGTest>() at gtest-param-util.h:574 0x1000025b0   
            EnsembleClustering::ParametrizedGTest_testParameter_Test::AddToRegistry() at ParametrizedGTest.cpp:22 0x100001d3f   
            __static_initialization_and_destruction_0() at ParametrizedGTest.cpp:22 0x100001349 
            _GLOBAL__sub_I_ParametrizedGTest.cpp() at ParametrizedGTest.cpp:32 0x100001424  
            <...more frames...> 
    gdb
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in googletest? Can you reproduce this error?

EDIT: I am on Mac OS X 10.8.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error, it compiles and runs fine for me. Is this all the code or is there more happening?

Comment: @rmhartog There's a lot of other code in the project, including other tests. But the code above is the entire parametrized test class, and if I exclude it from the build, everything works fine. Which version of Googletest are you using?

Comment: I'm using GoogleTest 1.6.0 with MinGW. Have you tried testing with another version, and on another system?

Comment: @rmhartog I'm using 1.6.0 as well. I have not tested other platforms, I need this to work on my current platform.

Comment: Have you tried moving the Test and Fixture definition out of the namespace and instead manually include your namespace classes explicitly? The error looks like there is some static initialisation of the test cases involved that happen before the actual main code runs.

Comment: And did you check if the `GTEST_HAS_PARAM_TEST` is set, maybe googletest simply does not support your platform.

Comment: @grundprinzip I've tried to move the definition of the parametrized test out of the namespace, but the situation remains the same.

Comment: @grundprinzip How do I check `GTEST_HAS_PARAM_TEST`?

Comment: #ifdef GTEST_HASH_PARAM_TEST
    // code that uses params
    #endif

Comment: @grundprinzip GTEST_HASH_PARAM_TEST is not set. too bad.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my example, I meant `GTEST_HAS_PARAM_TEST` not, `HASH`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source code of gtest the only case if there are no parametrized tests available is on Windows using VC7.1 with disabled exceptions:

```
// We don't support MSVC 7.1 with exceptions disabled now.  Therefore
// all the compilers we care about are adequate for supporting
// value-parameterized tests.
#define GTEST_HAS_PARAM_TEST 1
```

So, you'll need to check how your MinGW was built and probably update it? And can you run the gtest unit tests to see if they execute the typed parameters test?

More information on MinGW:

On their [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_use_Google_Test_on_MinGW?) they report that when using MinGW the following compile option for building gtest is required: `PATH/TO/configure CC="gcc -mno-cygwin" CXX="g++ -mno-cygwin"`.

Complete Example:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
namespace EnsembleClustering {

    class ParametrizedGTest: public testing::TestWithParam<int> {
    public:
        ParametrizedGTest();
        virtual ~ParametrizedGTest();
    };

    ParametrizedGTest::ParametrizedGTest() {
    }

    ParametrizedGTest::~ParametrizedGTest() {
    }

    TEST_P(ParametrizedGTest, testParameter) {
        int n = GetParam();
        EXPECT_EQ(n, GetParam());
    }

    INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(ParametrizedGTestInstance,
                            ParametrizedGTest,
                            ::testing::Values(100));

} /* namespace EnsembleClustering */


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I compiled this code using the following compiler call on Mac OS X 10.8:

```
g++ -IGTEST_INCLUDE_DIR -LGTEST_LIB_DIR -lgtest -o tt2 tt2.cpp
```

Where `GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR` and `GTEST_LIB_DIR` are the path where header and library files are stored. When you compile and execute, what happens?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X 10.8. I should have added that to the question before.

Comment: When I build this as a standalone project with these options: https://gist.github.com/4626770  - it works fine.

Comment: Well, it also works now in my original project! I haven't touched the code of the test, but I've changed the compiler settings. In particular, I removed the flag `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, which was the cause of another extremely strange crash. The bounty is still yours, since you really looked into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ChristianStaudt and @grundprinzip

I would like to point future readers to following link that explains this problem.
http://libcwd.sourceforge.net/reference-manual/group__enable__glibcxx__debug.html

This is a link to the documentation for GLIBCXX_DEBUG flag. It states the following important points.

- "Note that this flag changes the sizes and behavior of standard class templates such as std::vector, and therefore you can only link code compiled with debug mode and code compiled without debug mode if no instantiation of a container is passed between the two translation units."
- "When to use it

  It is a good idea to use this if you suspect problems related to iterators."

Now, if you look at the stack trace posted originally, the crash happens due to `vector<testing::internal::ParameterizedTestCaseInfoBase*>` as gtest tries to get an iterator on this container, using begin() method.

In my case, gtest lib was compiled **without** GLICXX_DEBUG flag, but my test code was compiled **with** this flag. The test code worked like a charm when I compiled without this flag.